# Arrays not getting sorted after async function

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native

On a screen on my app I have a `useEffect` hook that retrieves some info about a user for a notification, after that I want to get all the notifications array sorted by date, the problem is that the arrays doesn't seem to get sorted:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const arrayNotifications = [];
  const arrayRequests = [];

  notificationsAndRequests.forEach(async notif => {
    const senderSnapshot = await database().ref(`/users/${notif.sender}`).once('value');
    let senderImage = (senderSnapshot.val() && senderSnapshot.val().userImg);

    if (notif.sender == null) {
      const recieverSnapshot = await database().ref(`/users/${notif.sender}`).once('value');
      senderImage = (recieverSnapshot.val() && recieverSnapshot.val().userImg);
    }

    const element = {
      date: notif.date,
      id: notif.id,
      isInvitation: notif.isInvitation,
      message: notif.message,
      reciever: notif.reciever,
      sender: notif.sender,
      senderimage: senderImage,
      timestamp: notif.timestamp,
      title: notif.title,
      extraid: notif.extraid,
      requestid: notif.requestid,
      viewed: notif.viewed,
      status: notif.status || ''
    };

    if (notif.isInvitation) {
      arrayRequests.push(element);
    } else {
      arrayNotifications.push(element);
    }
  });
  const sortedNotifications = arrayNotifications.sort(
    (a, b) => Date.parse(mom(b.timestamp, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm').toDate())
    - Date.parse(mom(a.timestamp, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm').toDate())
  );
  const sortedRequests = arrayRequests.sort(
    (a, b) => Date.parse(mom(b.timestamp, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm').toDate())
    - Date.parse(mom(a.timestamp, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm').toDate())
  );

  setNotifications(sortedNotifications);
  setRequestsNotifications(sortedRequests);
}, [notificationsAndRequests]);
```

Both `sortedRequests` and `sortedNotifications` should be ordered by the `timestamp` property of the `notif` object (`timestamp` is just a string formatted as a date).
Should I sort both `arrayRequests` and `arrayNotifications` instead?

Comment: `.forEach(async` never works like you expect - use a for loop instead

Comment: as @Bravo mentioned, try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`async` on your `forEach` is not waiting for `arrayNotifications` and `arrayRequests` results. You need to wrap your `async` logic in another function and then update your states there

```
const sortNotificationsAndRequests = async (notificationsAndRequests) => {
  const arrayNotifications = [];
  const arrayRequests = [];

 for(const notif of notificationsAndRequests) {
   const senderSnapshot = await database().ref(`/users/${notif.sender}`).once('value');
    let senderImage = (senderSnapshot.val() && senderSnapshot.val().userImg);

    if (notif.sender == null) {
      const recieverSnapshot = await database().ref(`/users/${notif.sender}`).once('value');
      senderImage = (recieverSnapshot.val() && recieverSnapshot.val().userImg);
    }

    const element = {
      date: notif.date,
      id: notif.id,
      isInvitation: notif.isInvitation,
      message: notif.message,
      reciever: notif.reciever,
      sender: notif.sender,
      senderimage: senderImage,
      timestamp: notif.timestamp,
      title: notif.title,
      extraid: notif.extraid,
      requestid: notif.requestid,
      viewed: notif.viewed,
      status: notif.status || ''
    };

    if (notif.isInvitation) {
      arrayRequests.push(element);
    } else {
      arrayNotifications.push(element);
    }
 }

  const sortedNotifications = arrayNotifications.sort(
    (a, b) => Date.parse(mom(b.timestamp, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm').toDate())
    - Date.parse(mom(a.timestamp, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm').toDate())
  );
  const sortedRequests = arrayRequests.sort(
    (a, b) => Date.parse(mom(b.timestamp, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm').toDate())
    - Date.parse(mom(a.timestamp, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm').toDate())
  );

  setNotifications(sortedNotifications);
  setRequestsNotifications(sortedRequests);
}

useEffect(() => {
  //call the new function to update your states
  sortNotificationsAndRequests(notificationsAndRequests)
}, [notificationsAndRequests]);
```